# CSS incompatibilidade no alinhamento Firefox e Chrome

Tags: html, css

Não estou conseguindo deixar o mesmo padrão de alinhamento da imagem **hallo-top_fd2.png** no navegador chrome, aonde estou errando?

Grato

```css
#container {
  display: table-row-group;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  right: -34px;
}

#container figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 185px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<figure id="container">
  <img src="img/hallo-top_fd2.png" />  
  <figcaption>FUNDAMENTAL II</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Firefox
[image: Texto]

Chrome
[image: Texto]

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o problema é que o *user-agente* do **Chrome** não reconhece `position: relative` em um elemento com `display: table-row-group;`. Repare que na Aba **Computed** do **DevTools**, o elemento até pega o *style* do `right: -34px`, mas o `position` continua como `static`, o  *user-agente*  não deixa muda-lo, dessa forma o elemento filho com `positino: absolute` não fica relativo ai pai, pois o `position: relative` do pai que está com `display: table-row-group;` não está sendo aplicado no final das contas...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Essa é a explicação do problema.*** Agora sobre a solução a sugestão é tirar esse `display: table-row-group;` do container pai, pois sinceramente, não faz sentido algum usar um `display` de `<tbody>` em uma `<div>`. Tente usar `flex` ou `grid` que vc vai se dar melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]